# pdf conversion Using java library

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I am willing to convert xhtml files into pdf/a format or  pdf files to pdf/a format..  Can anyone please suggest which java library I can use..
Thank you

I will make my example more specific

I have a simple html file xyz.html

> ```
> <html><body>
> hello
> <br>
> <font style = "Helvetica">hello</font>
> <br>
> </body></html>
> ```

java code :

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(pdffile);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fout);
pdfWriter.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFA1B);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(xyz.html);
document.open();
HashMap<String, Object> Provider = new HashMap<String, Object>();
DefaultFontProvider def = new 
Provider.put(HTMLWorker.FONT_PROVIDER, def);
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.setProviders(Provider);
htmlWorker.parse(fr);
```

I get the error   com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica

Comment: I am using iText for conversion but it doesnot provide any option to convert from pdf to pdf/a .. while I try to convert from xhtml to pdf/a 1a or pdf/a 1b using pdfWriter.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFA1B) get an error "All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica" .. can anyone suggest any solution

Comment: What version of iText are you using?

Answer (score 2):

try the flying soucer: http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: Seems flying saucer doesn't support PDF/A yet, at least in latest maven release 9.0.7.

Comment: Could you take a look at the question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 1):

Check for `iText` library which has support for both `Java` and `.net` 
http://itextpdf.com/

Few examples in the below link : 
http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html

<strike>This is proprietory but</strike> Its really a smart enterprise library and has good customer support.

Comment: do you have any idea how to solve the problem.. when I set pdfWriter.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFA1B), I get an error "All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica"

Comment: iText is no propietary software!!! It's open source, under AGPL, and a commercial licence is availble for fee if you want to free yourself from the limitation of the AGPL. Also, you might want to point to the official [examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php) and [keywords](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php)

Comment: To @ranjan, you can have a look at a PDF/A example [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=226).

Comment: @AlexisPigeon updated the answer appropriately. Thanks for your input. Since we purchased the license for iText in our company, I had a wrong impression that its proprietary.

Comment: still I couldnot get any solution for the error, the tutorial provide just a simple example to add a paragraph to the document.. I want to convert the html file to pdf/a

Comment: googling error gives me this forum post http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-embed-a-font-in-pdfa-td3317100.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Apache FOP project](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), it supports conversion of xml files to pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Expected Behavior, and we've developed a SaaS application called DocRaptor that converts HTML to PDF using Prince XML as our rendering engine. DocRaptor uses HTTP POST requests to generate PDF files, and can be used with Java.

Here's a link to our Java example:

[DocRaptor Java example](http://docraptor.com/documentation/examples_java)

And a link to DocRaptor's home page:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

DocRaptor IS a subscription based service, but our free plan allows you to create up to 5 documents per month, and we don't embed watermarks or restrict the size of free documents.